# Limit the printing while using a FOR LOOP

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, printing, limit

I would like to know how to limit the amount of times I can print a for loop, I couldnt find anything so far. Any help?
Thanks in advance

```
    def sixMulti(x,y): # Multiples of six
    nList = range(x,y)
    bySix = list(filter(lambda x: x%6==0, nList))
    for i in bySix:                             # square root function
        sqrt = list(map(lambda x: x**0.5, bySix))
    #round(sqrt, 3)
    #f"The number is {sqrt:.2f}"
    num = [ '%.2f' % e for e in sqrt]
    for i in range(0, len(num)):
        myList = ("Value is ", bySix[i], " and the square root is ", num[i])
        print(myList)
return bySix, num
```

Comment: ('Value is ', 6, ' and the square root is ', '2.45')
('Value is ', 12, ' and the square root is ', '3.46')
('Value is ', 18, ' and the square root is ', '4.24')
('Value is ', 24, ' and the square root is ', '4.90')
('Value is ', 30, ' and the square root is ', '5.48')
('Value is ', 36, ' and the square root is ', '6.00')
('Value is ', 42, ' and the square root is ', '6.48')
('Value is ', 6, ' and the square root is ', '2.45')
('Value is ', 12, ' and the square root is ', '3.46')....
([6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42],
 ['2.45', '3.46', '4.24', '4.90', '5.48', '6.00', '6.48'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function prints the list only one:

```
>>> sixMulti(1, 47)
('Value is ', 6, ' and the square root is ', '2.45')
('Value is ', 12, ' and the square root is ', '3.46')
('Value is ', 18, ' and the square root is ', '4.24')
('Value is ', 24, ' and the square root is ', '4.90')
('Value is ', 30, ' and the square root is ', '5.48')
('Value is ', 36, ' and the square root is ', '6.00')
('Value is ', 42, ' and the square root is ', '6.48')
```

If you have this output *x* times, then you call this function *x* times :) And in

```
for i in bySix:                             # square root function
    sqrt = list(map(lambda x: x**0.5, bySix))
```

you are re-assigning `sqrt` on every iteration. Having only

```
sqrt = list(map(lambda x: x**0.5, bySix))
```

is sufficient.